# RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device(related to no CUDA Toolkit?

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I'm trying to reproduce the result of the article Tran-SVNet using the code provided in https://github.com/IsabelFunke/Trans-SVNet

However, when I'm executing the line

```
python generate_LFB.py --skip_train
```

I got

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
```

Here's the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_LFB.py", line 617, in <module>
    main()
  File "generate_LFB.py", line 613, in main
    (val_num_each, test_num_each))
  File "generate_LFB.py", line 571, in train_model
    outputs_feature = model_LFB.forward(inputs).data.cpu().numpy()
  File "/path/miniconda3/envs/torch151/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 153, in forward
    return self.module(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])
  File "/path/miniconda3/envs/torch151/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "generate_LFB.py", line 241, in forward
    x = self.share.forward(x)
  File "/path/miniconda3/envs/torch151/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 100, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/path/miniconda3/envs/torch151/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/path/miniconda3/envs/torch151/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/activation.py", line 94, in forward
    return F.relu(input, inplace=self.inplace)
  File "/path/miniconda3/envs/torch151/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1061, in relu
    result = torch.relu_(input)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
```

I'm very new to using cluster and CUDA(and posting on stack overflow as well :) So if there's any missing information, please kindly point it out.

I'm running this program on a cluster without CUDA toolkit, but other people's programs work fine.

Here's what I got by typing

```
nvidia-smi
```

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 530.30.02              Driver Version: 530.30.02    CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060         On | 00000000:18:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 31%   27C    P8               18W / 170W|      1MiB / 12288MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Nothing will happen if I type

```
nvcc --version
```

I also tried the following command:

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
print(torch.backends.cudnn.enabled)
device = torch.device('cuda')
print(torch.cuda.get_device_properties(device))
print(torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0]).cuda())
```

The result is

```
1.5.1
True
True
_CudaDeviceProperties(name='NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060', major=8, minor=6, total_memory=12044MB, multi_processor_count=28)
tensor([1., 2.], device='cuda:0')
```

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: You probably need a newer version of PyTorch, that version predates the release of the RTX 3060

Comment: The version of Pytorch you are using hasn't been built with support for your GPU3

Comment: Thanks, I'll try upgrading my pytorch